# Link from one iOS cached bookmarked homescreen website to another

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, caching

I've got two simple webpages, both are correctly cached and are added to my iPad homescreen as individual bookmarks for use offline.

Each has a link to a named anchor tag in the other, this works fine when online, but when I go offline, both apps are cached, when I click either link, it opens the webpage directly and as it is offline; it fails, rather than use the cached version that is already available.

I'm not entirely sure what this process would be called, so my searches have been pretty poor.

My question is, is it actually possible to link between two cached homescreen bookmarks, and if so can someone point me in the right direction on how to do that please?

Comment: "Homescreen bookmarks" are called "webapps" when they're designed specifically to be run as a standalone app. Apple has some decent documentation and best practices about them. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to do what you want using only webapps. I think you'd need a webview wrapper like Cordova, because in order for one app to open another you need to register a custom URL scheme, something you can't do with a pure webapp.

Comment: Webapps and Cordova, thank you. I'll look into both of those and see if I can find out more info, thanks again.